# GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate (Google REST API)

Tags: ios, rest, google-drive-api

1.I need to create a folder in google drive.And I use this code to do this(official code from google developers page):

```
GTLRDrive_File *metadata = [GTLRDrive_File object];
metadata.name = @"Invoices";
metadata.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:metadata
                                                               uploadParameters:nil];
query.fields = @"id";
[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLRDrive_File *file,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File ID %@", file.identifier);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

And the folder creates  fine!
The problem is that each time I run the App , the code creates dublicates of the folder in my Google Drive.But I need to create only one folder of that name and kind.
I know its a rookie question, but I cannot figure it out how to do this.And I know that I should compare( GTLRDrive_File *file) identifier (as it is a unique string),but how do I do it?

2.So the question is :How do check if the identifier is already created and compare it ?
I understand that to fulfil my tsk I should check if the Identifier is exists,if not I should create it, and if its doesn't exist do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Drive API does allow multiple files with duplicate names. File/folder names are not unique, but identifiers are.

What you likely want to do is:

1. Check if a folder with the same name exists
2. If not, then create the folder
3. If it already exists, then use the identifier of the existing folder.

How to check if a folder exists. This is swift, but it's trivial to convert it to ObjC

```
func getFolderID(name: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()

    // Add "and '\(self.user.profile!.email!)' in owners" to only list folders owned by a specific GIDGoogleUser.
    query.q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '\(name)'"

    driveService.executeQuery(query) { (_, queryResults, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let fileList = queryResults as! GTLRDrive_FileList

        completion(fileList.files?.first?.identifier)
    }
}
```

And then you'd call `getFolderID` in this manner:

```
getFolderID(name: "my-folder-name") { (folderID) in
    if let folderID = folderID {
        print("Found folder with ID: \(folderID)")
    } else {
        print("Folder does not exist")
    }
}
```

File name search is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do a `files.get` of the id. It will return status 200 and the file object if it's there, or 404 not found.

Comment: Could you please,be more specific in your answer? Code example,maybe?

Comment: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId} See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get

Comment: how do I use it in Objective-C ?Thanks for trying to answer my question, but your answers are not making anything clearer.